# How to create a generic class type as subset of another type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a generic type, which is constrained to be a subset of another specific type. It should not be allowed to add new properties or override the type of existing properties, but it should be allowed to implement only a subset of the specified type. This is what I would expect:

```ts
type Foo = { a: string; b: number; }

// Case1: valid
new MyClass<{ a: string }>()

// Case2: invalid (does not exist in both types)
new MyClass<{ b: number }>()

// Case3: invalid (does not exist in both types)
new MyClass<{ c: string }>()

// Case4: invalid (does not exist in both types)
// invalid (wrong type of a)
new MyClass<{ a: number }>()

// Case5: invalid (wrong type of a)
new MyClass<{ a: undefined }>()
new MyClass<{ a: null }>()
```

What I would need is something like this:

```ts
// Pseudo code (subsets does not exist):
class MyClass<T subsets Foo> {}
```

Things, that `extends Foo` does, which I don’t want:

1. Allow additional properties to be declared (case3 would be valid)
2. Enforce all properties of `Foo` (case1 would be invalid)

Things that  `extends Partial<Foo>` does, which I don’t want:

1. Allow additional properties to be declared (case3 would be valid)
2. Values of all properties can be `undefined`

---

**Current state**

I have created a type that creates a subset of another type:

```ts
type Subset<T extends S, S> = Pick<T, keyof S>
```

but I can not get it to work with as a constraint for classes …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create a restriction that does not allow any extra members to be specified, by mandating that if any extra properties are present, they are of type `never`. We can do this using `Exclude<keyof T, keyof S>` to get only the extra keys and `Record`:

```
type Foo = { a: string; b: number; }

type Subset<T, S> = Pick<S, Extract<keyof T, keyof S>> & Partial<Record<Exclude<keyof T, keyof S>, never>>
class MyClass<T extends Subset<T, Foo>> {
    constructor(public t?:T){
        if(t == null) return;
        // t has no accessible members as far as the compiler is concerned 
        // but we can assign it to Partial<Foo> and access fields like this
        let d: Partial<Foo> = t; 
        d.a // works
    }
}

// Case1: valid
new MyClass<{ a: string }>()

// Case2: invalid (does not exist in both types)
new MyClass<{ b: number }>()

// Case3: invalid (does not exist in both types) 
// This would be invalid under extends Partial<Foo> also
new MyClass<{ c: string }>()

// Case3b: invalid (has extra props)
// This would be valid under extends Partial<Foo> but is not under Partial<Foo> & Record<Exclude<keyof T, keyof Foo>, never>
new MyClass<{  a: string, c: string }>()

// Case4: invalid (does not exist in both types)
// invalid (wrong type of a)
new MyClass<{ a: number }>()

// Case5: invalid (wrong type of a) only with strict null checks !
new MyClass<{ a: undefined }>()
new MyClass<{ a: null }>()
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Foo%20%3D%20%7B%20a%3A%20string%3B%20b%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Subset%3CT%2C%20S%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CS%2C%20Extract%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20keyof%20S%3E%3E%20%26%20Partial%3CRecord%3CExclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20keyof%20S%3E%2C%20never%3E%3E%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%3CT%20extends%20Subset%3CT%2C%20Foo%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20t%3F%3AT)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if(t%20%3D%3D%20null)%20return%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20t%20has%20no%20accessible%20members%20as%20far%20as%20the%20compiler%20is%20concerned%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20but%20we%20can%20assign%20it%20to%20Partial%3CFoo%3E%20and%20access%20fields%20like%20this%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20d%3A%20Partial%3CFoo%3E%20%3D%20t%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20d.a%20%2F%2F%20works%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Case1%3A%20valid%0D%0Anew%20MyClass%3C%7B%20a%3A%20string%20%7D%3E()%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Case2%3A%20invalid%20(does%20not%20exist%20in%20both%20types)%0D%0Anew%20MyClass%3C%7B%20b%3A%20number%20%7D%3E()%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Case3%3A%20invalid%20(does%20not%20exist%20in%20both%20types)%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20would%20be%20invalid%20under%20extends%20Partial%3CFoo%3E%20also%0D%0Anew%20MyClass%3C%7B%20c%3A%20string%20%7D%3E()%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Case3b%3A%20invalid%20(has%20extra%20props)%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20would%20be%20valid%20under%20extends%20Partial%3CFoo%3E%20but%20is%20not%20under%20Partial%3CFoo%3E%20%26%20Record%3CExclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20keyof%20Foo%3E%2C%20never%3E%0D%0Anew%20MyClass%3C%7B%20%20a%3A%20string%2C%20c%3A%20string%20%7D%3E()%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Case4%3A%20invalid%20(does%20not%20exist%20in%20both%20types)%0D%0A%2F%2F%20invalid%20(wrong%20type%20of%20a)%0D%0Anew%20MyClass%3C%7B%20a%3A%20number%20%7D%3E()%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Case5%3A%20invalid%20(wrong%20type%20of%20a)%20only%20with%20strict%20null%20checks%20!%0D%0Anew%20MyClass%3C%7B%20a%3A%20undefined%20%7D%3E()%0D%0Anew%20MyClass%3C%7B%20a%3A%20null%20%7D%3E()%0D%0A)

Comment: Wow, that works really well, although I am still trying to get my head around it. I discovered another case that should be invalid, but is valid here: `new MyClass<{ a: undefined }>()` (or `null`) It should throw an error, because `a` should be of type `string`. (see case 5 in my original question)

Comment: @Afterlame That will work only if you enable strict null checks (and if you enable it, these cases are already errors) , otherwise `string` really means `string|null| undefined` so there is no way to exclude those cases.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. Forgot to do that in the TS Playground! Thanks, this is amazing!